# TypeScript: Promise.all doesn't handle union types

Tags: typescript, promise, union-types

I have the following piece of code that results in compile error in TypeScript:

```
type Promisable = (() => Promise<string>) | (() => Promise<number>);

const func = async (promisable: Promisable) => {
  await Promise.all([promisable()]);
};
```

The error is as follows

> No overload matches this call.
>    The last overload gave the following error.
>      Argument of type '(Promise | Promise)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable>'.
>        The types returned by 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.

For the record, removing the union type works as intended:

```
type Promisable = () => Promise<string>;

const func = async (promisable: Promisable) => {
  await Promise.all([promisable()]);
};
```

You can see the error for yourself here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYEsDOBDARgG2gXigAoiBKKfAPlkVTQgB41g4UA7Ac0vIB9iyK1eMnSM2AVyRYIcbgG4AsACgAxgjbMoAM3FsVFKBjQg9xMLXTY8ALhojMuCOSpQA3sqiGA7hhTA7dBAAdBg4OEQA2ub2VhBkALqkikoAvnJAA

Is it not possible to use union types in combination with `Promise.all`?

EDIT:
I know it's possible to use something like `() => Promise<string|number>` instead. But in an advanced application with a lot of asynchronous functions and big types, it is not easy to  convert union of functions into function of union. It's not very practical from the code perspective as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

This is one of the cases, where [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) with current [promise type declarations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/065a996345fcfafd3c744d2a724a1ae9f31f9ab0/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L41-L113) fails.
Simplest solution is to just add the generic type argument manually:

```
const promisable: Promisable = ...
const res = await Promise.all<string | number>([promisable()]); 
// res: (string|number)[]
```

You might infer `string | number` automatically:

```
type PromiseReturn<T> = T extends () => Promise<infer I> ? I : never
const res = await Promise.all<PromiseReturn<Promisable>>([promisable()]);
```

With [TypeScript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/): More complex, potentially nested Promise types can be resolved and flattened with a [custom recursive `Awaited` type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#recursive-conditional-types) like this:

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? Awaited<U> : T;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMwJ5mHABSggFsBLAZwEMAjAG3wF44AKFgSjkYD5DjyKwADwUYUMgDsA5t04AfVhy68ipSsIkBXEjWBRZAbiy58qgcABKwGJqgShAFV7MHcUDGASAJhVacefGqCQpIAZnpwAJK8APxRcABccBLAAG56GBhewADGdFRQ+DkQEqJwYPyUtAxJZlX0wJnoxaXwUACMXHBUAO5UZPB1ggB0VHR0ImKSUnAKWjp63CwA2hVB1cAcALrsBnAA9PtwhRRJLKLi0rPJ2rpQ7MtbGC1lUABMXb39g5UjYxNDSzWWz2IYbbhLVa-DbbXYHI4nM4XabXeZ3B5PTDoHB4OAAQT6A2AXkczjgrncnh8gXMABkyABrYRhCIAVVi+MJHhJ7MS5KMzRKrwAzJ8uTT1KNxkICd9iUIrDY7A4TEIwQ0IZC1gIYewdntDsdgKdWMirnNbnoMUA)

---

---

### Old answer

**Update:** The `awaited` type operator is [delayed to later versions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37198#issuecomment-604160291) - not clear whether it will be released at all.

---

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33707). Good news: [TS 3.9](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37198) (beta soon) will come out with [improved promise types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35998):

> I would like to reintroduce the `awaited` type operator from [#17077](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17077) to meet our needs for a mechanism to recursively unwrap a Promise-like type for methods like `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, `Promise.allSettled`, `Promise.prototype.then`, and `Promise.prototype.catch`.

[Type declarations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35998/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.js&file-filters%5B%5D=.ts#diff-f70f4dbf5d69748c094312b75e6599c2) of `Promise.all` and others use the new `awaited` type operator. If you [test with the nightly build](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.9.0-dev.20200323#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMwJ5mHABSggFsBLAZwEMAjAG3wF44AKFgSjkYD5DjyKwADwUYUMgDsA5t04AfVhy68ipSsIkBXEjWBRZAbgwYAJsADGdKlHzmIE0XDD9KtBgC4%20a6vWAY7DvA2FACMXHBUAO5UZPDO3m7ASgD0yXDBIZ6i4tJwClo6ev72jsEATOFRMfCqAsAAdFR0dCwA2vECiRwAuuwGcKnpwBRlnizZklJ5cAW6UOyt3RhAA), `Promise.all` now correctly resolves to `Promise<(string | number)[]>`:

```
type Promisable = (() => Promise<string>) | (() => Promise<number>);

declare const promisable: Promisable
const res = await Promise.all([promisable()]); // res: (string | number)[]
```

In contrast, TS 3.8 [can't handle it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMwJ5mHABSggFsBLAZwEMAjAG3wF44AKFgSjkYD5DjyKwADwUYUMgDsA5t04AfVhy68ipSsIkBXEjWBRZAbgwYAJsADGdKlHzmIE0XDD9KtBgC4%20a6vWAY7DvA2FACMXHBUAO5UZPDO3m7ASgD0yXDBIZ6i4tJwClo6ev72jsEATOFRMfCqAsAAdFR0dCwA2vECiRwAuuwGcKlwesRQADRedSJiklKt3bz1i3AmmgAWq0A). For versions < 3.9,  you can [manually assign](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=6&ssc=92&pln=5&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMwJ5mHABSggFsBLAZwEMAjAG3wF44AKFgSjkYD5DjyKwADwUYUMgDsA5t04AfVhy68ipSsIkBXEjWBRZAbgwYAJsADGdKlHzmIE0XDD9KtBgC4%20a6vWAY7DvA2FFxwVADuVGTwqgLAAHRUdHQiYpJScApaOnrcLADazt5uwBwAuuwGcAD01XDBniyi4tKZcNm6UOz5ZUA) the generic type argument:

```
declare const promisable: Promisable
const res = await Promise.all<string | number>([promisable()]); // res: (string | number)[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such a verbose type, this will do:

```js
type Promisable = (() => Promise<string|number>);
const func = async (promisable: Promisable) => {
  await Promise.all([promisable()]);
};
```

Comment: In this particular example, it will work. When having multiple, already ready async functions, for example for obtaining data from the API, each with it's own type signature, then the Promise of an union it's not really possible.